# unable to call a service using post method

Tags: angular, typescript

using postman i am able to call a service but same can't make it from angular.

below is my script in angular 7 typescript

```
   save() {
   this.sales.detail=this.empList;

   let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
     });    
     let options = {
    headers: httpHeaders
     };     
     let body = JSON.stringify(this.sales);     
     this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Sales/Order/', body, options).subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log("Updated the customer");
     });


}
```

the postman script is

```
var settings = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "http://localhost:9220/api/Sales/Order",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
   "content-type": "application/json",
   "cache-control": "no-cache",
   "postman-token": "4c5861cf-be10-6a46-0b77-27d862d9799f"
 },
"processData": false,
 "data": "{mydata}"

 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
console.log(response);
 });
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:9220/api/Sales/Order", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:9220/api/Sales/Order: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:9220/api/Sales/Order"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase

Comment: For http, you are using HttpClient right? `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Sales/Order', body).subscribe((res)=>{
    console.log("Updated the customer");
});
```